# value share inside a mutate - dplyr package

Tags: r

I would like calculate value share of each class in each store. Is that possibe inside a mutate?

```
data<-read_excel("data.xlsx")

data2<-data%>%
  group_by(Store, Class)%>%
  summarise(Values=sum(Value))%>%
  mutate(Values2=Valor/???)
```

I have a dataset like this:

```
    Store   Class   Value
    A   1   100
    A   2   200
    A   3   300
    A   1   200
    A   2   400
    A   3   600
    B   1   10
    B   2   20
    B   3   30
    B   1   20
    B   2   40
    B   3   60
```

Thanks!

Comment: library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Store, Class) %>% 
  mutate(share = Value / sum(Value))    Do you mean this? Or could you please make clear what you mean with value share?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example It will be better if you share part of `data` and expected output along with question. Please add output of `dput(head(data,20))` in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After grouping the data frame, you can sum your values column twice and see that operation behave differently: Inside `summarise`, it will add up all the values for each combination of store and class. Then in the `mutate` in the next line, it will assume you're stripping away the second layer of grouping (in this case, class), and give you sums by store. So then `mutate(share = Value / sum(Value))` yields the share with respect to the store, for each class.

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- "Store   Class   Value
    A   1   100
A   2   200
A   3   300
A   1   200
A   2   400
A   3   600
B   1   10
B   2   20
B   3   30
B   1   20
B   2   40
B   3   60" %>% readr::read_table2()

df %>%
  group_by(Store, Class) %>%
  summarise(Value = sum(Value)) %>%
  mutate(share = Value / sum(Value))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Groups:   Store [2]
#>   Store Class Value share
#>   <chr> <int> <int> <dbl>
#> 1 A         1   300 0.167
#> 2 A         2   600 0.333
#> 3 A         3   900 0.5  
#> 4 B         1    30 0.167
#> 5 B         2    60 0.333
#> 6 B         3    90 0.5
```

Created on 2018-06-15 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).